# Is it ever useful to consider a long exact sequence as a chain complex?

Tags: homological-algebra

Here are two common ways of obtaining chain complexes with vanishing homology:

1. Chain complexes that compute the reduced homology of a contractible space
2. Chain complexes that arise as a "long exact sequence in homology" induced by a short exact sequence of chain complexes

These two examples seem to be on different footing.  It is easy to think of useful maps within a type:

- for 1), a continuous map of contractible spaces induces a chain map
- for 2), a map of short exact sequences induces a map on long exact sequences

but I cannot really imagine a map between these two types, mostly because the three-fold periodicity in type 2) seems utterly incompatible with the ethos of type 1).  The two types seem like unrelated notions that happen to have the same mathematical definition.

So here is my precise question, trying to see if there is any crossover:

> Suppose (X,A) is a pair of spaces, $A \subseteq X$ so that there is a short exact sequence of singular chains $0 \to C_\bullet A \to C_\bullet X \to C_\bullet(X,A) \to 0$.  Is it possible to functorially construct a filtered contractible space $\Lambda = \Lambda(X,A)$ with $\Lambda_0 \subseteq \Lambda_1 \subseteq \ldots$ so that
>
> - $H_\bullet(\Lambda_{3k},\Lambda_{3k-1}) \cong H_k A$,
> - $H_\bullet(\Lambda_{3k+1},\Lambda_{3k}) \cong H_k X$, and
> - $H_\bullet(\Lambda_{3k+2},\Lambda_{3k-1}) \cong H_k(X, A)$,
>   so that the spectral sequence of the filtered space $\Lambda$ recovers the long exact sequence of (X,A) as the $E^1$-page?

Motivation: I am writing a Macaulay2 package that makes it easy for the user to generate long exact sequences.  I originally considered returning such a sequence as a "ChainComplex" object, since this data type already exists in M2 and can be used by other functions.  Then I decided that this is not so convenient, actually, because it obscures the threefold periodicity.  But now I wonder if it could ever be useful to consider a long exact sequence as a chain complex.